# Unable to access Google Iot core v1beta1 discovery api

Tags: iot, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to access Google Iot core v1beta1 discovery api using the link https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta1.
Whenever i try to access it shows

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Discovery document not found for API service: cloudiot.googleapis.com format: rest version: v1beta1",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Am i missing something in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1beta1 has been deprecated. Please use v1

https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1